# Good video lectures for studying Calculus?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, online-resources

I am looking for a good online video resource to start studying Calculus. I am studying it alone, not part of any school or university. Trying to learn and enhance my mathematical skills.
Thanks!

Comment: This is not really a Mathematica question, or are you looking for a calculus video with Mathematica as tool?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not the appropriate place. I wish to study mathematics. I was under the impression a math forum would be a good place to consult. I am not sure what it means 'a calculus video with Mathematica as tool'

Comment: [`Mathematica` is a software tool](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)

Comment: Appreciate your effort, me too doing it alone, keep in touch.  I feel MIT lectures should be good, but nothing can replace books :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest the following: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/video-lectures/

I learned a lot from these lectures (not the ones in the link but the multivariable calculus ones) but these are just as good!

Comment: This link has better notes and designed for internet self learning.
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/index.htm

Comment: The link in the Answer to ocw.mit.edu appears to be dead. The link in @vincentmathew is still good. Link rot; link rot and taxes.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kahn Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/) has many mathematics video courses.

Answer (score 2):

Gilbert Strang's [Highlights of Calculus](http://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/courses/highlights-of-calculus/index.htm) videos are probably good.

Comment: Having watched them, I can attest that they are *actually* good. Good recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the ones already mentioned by the other posters, I highly recommend you watch these excellent lectures by [Selwyn Hollis](http://www.online.math.uh.edu/HoustonACT/videocalculus/).

As well, here are some hard to find videos corresponding to the 11th edition of Thomas Calculus that I enjoyed a long time ago. While the book links all appear to be dead, and not all of the videos work, most of the videos do work, and the deliverers are outstanding: [Thomas](http://www.tutor-homework.com/Math_Help/Calculus.html).

I am surprised that the latter are still extant.

Answer (score 1):

You may find Adrian Banner's **Calculus Lifesaver** course useful. The series of 24+ videos are available at http://press.princeton.edu/video/banner/ and are also provided on the iTunes Store as Podcasts. The quality of the videos is variable, but the exposition is thorough, and his style is engaging.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial should definitely be your starting point. Grant helps you team math in the best possible way such that you retain the concept in best possible way.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/)
I myself used Tom Apostol's *Calculus* volume 1.(I am not really an expert )
[MIT Open courseware]

Answer (score 0):

The web site www.academicearth.org has a wide variety of entire courses in mathematics, especially in calculus (Not to mention history, philosophy, psychology, etc.). It's one of my favorite sites!

Answer (score 0):

I studies Single variable calculus from Thomas Finney and currently doing Multi-variable calculus from Kenneth Kuttler.

NOTE: In Video lecture for Multi-variable Calculus by Edward Frenkel of UC berkeley, in the first lecture he is referring to an equation (function y=f(x)) and he says that there are 2 "**independent**" variables and 1 equation, so number of independent variables minus number of equations gives us the dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The video lectures at the "best" schools tend to be less systematic and orderly. All are useful, but if you are using videos to self-teach I would suggest the UMKC calculus 1 lectures by Delaware. There is no live audience, and thus no stammering, no showing up and teaching off the top of one's head. More progressive and orderly.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend learning Calculus from the ground up with Professor Leonard. His video lectures are comprehensive, comprehensible, and help the math stick long after you've watched his videos. I completed his Calc 1 and Calc 2 courses. I am halfway through his Calc 3 videos. I suggest starting here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF797E961509B4EB5

The other recommendations such as the Strang Lectures and the 3Blue1Brown Essence of Calculus lectures make a great supplement, but I do not recommend them as the way to build your foundation.

The Apostol books can be considered the bible of Calculus. They are wonderful texts, but they are not for beginners.